# Why do I see the directory structure on a Web server and not the default index page?

Tags: apache, configuration

I am developing a Java application and I have to integrate a Perl application's code in it. The service has been provisioned on a CGI server.

When I am copying Perl files to the server location, index files are supposed to be automatically invoked. But when I am testing that URL, it is showing me the directory structure and not the default index page.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  I'm guessing English might not be your first language.  Could you try and clean up your question and maybe provide some sample output you're seeing?

Comment: New Apache servers are often configured to display the directory contents when no `index.html`, `index.htm`, `welcome.html` or similar file are found. You can disable such a feature; change what filenames are displayed by default or create such a file. What server are you using?

Comment: I get a chance to talk with the developer of this application, what he told me is to you have to configure  .htaccess file that is in the directory has this line "DirectoryIndex index.pl" which should tell the server to serve up that as the default page. I have done this but still its not working

Comment: downvoters, please be kind with newcommers: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/07/kicking-off-the-summer-of-love/

Answer (score 1):

You chaneg the defaut directory listing function of Apache using the DirectoryIndex directive as described in the [Apache Documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex)

So if you want myprog.pl to run, instead of seeing a directory index, then you need a directive similar to:

```
    DirectoryIndex myprog.pl
```

Your exact directive will be similar, but may differ depending on file paths.

Comment: I get a chance to talk with the developer of this application, what he told me is to you have to configure  .htaccess file that is in the directory has this line "DirectoryIndex index.pl" which should tell the server to serve up that as the default page

Comment: as long as your program is called index.pl.  if your program is called something other than index.pl, you'll need to substitute your file's name for 'index.pl'